# pysimplegui table: Is there a get or set type feature for table"s vertical scrollbar?

Tags: pysimplegui

I have a tall (a few thousand lines, sorted alphbetically), 2 column table, displayed about 15 rows at a time. Users scroll to the part of it they want to see.  But they need to be able to leave that page in the app, and later return to it, and without starting the scolling search again.  And it needs a "Page Up",Page Down feature, to view the vicinity of interest.  Easily done if tables can set and get a scrollbar position index.  But I don't see how to do that?   Does the Table element  have any such methods?

Answer (score 1):

Method `set_vscroll_position` of element can work, but it may need more job to check the ratio to scroll a page up/down.

```py
def set_vscroll_position(self, percent_from_top):
    """
    Attempts to set the vertical scroll postition for an element's Widget
    :param percent_from_top: From 0 to 1.0, the percentage from the top to move scrollbar to
    :type percent_from_top:  (float)
    """
```

Here demo code with tkinter code for `sg.Table` with vertical scrollbar only

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def scroll_table(event):

    if event == 'Top':
        table.set_vscroll_position(0.0)
        # table.Widget.yview_moveto(0.0)
    elif event == 'Bottom':
        table.set_vscroll_position(1.0)
        # table.Widget.yview_moveto(1.0)
    elif event == 'PgUp':
        table.Widget.yview_scroll(-1, 'pages')
    elif event == 'PgDn':
        table.Widget.yview_scroll(+1, 'pages')

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 11))

newlist = [[f"Cell ({row+1:0>2d}, {col+1:0>2d})" for col in range(4)] for row in range(50)]
COL_HEADINGS = ["Date", "Ref", "ID", "Owner"]

layout = [
    [sg.Table(values=newlist, headings=COL_HEADINGS, auto_size_columns=False,
     col_widths=(20,)*4, num_rows=10, justification='center', enable_events=True,
     alternating_row_color='green', select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_EXTENDED,
     key='-TABLE-')],
    [sg.Button('Top'), sg.Button('Bottom')],
]

window = sg.Window('Table', layout, finalize=True)
table = window['-TABLE-']
window.bind('<Prior>', "PgUp")
window.bind('<Next>', "PgDn")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ("Top", "Bottom", "PgUp", "PgDn"):
        scroll_table(event)

window.close()
```

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks Jason - you're brilliant!    I'm pretty sure I can tweak this code to a version that will do just what I need.   But ... a question about this code : how are the  PgUp and PgDn  features controlled?  Not with buttons apparently.   Also, where did you find this?  Apparently, I'm not (yet) looking in all the rightly places.

Comment: You can also do it by button, but I thought keyboard event maybe good for  it, so you can do them by different ways. for binding tkinter events, you can refer https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#binding-tkiner-events. Also more detail in https://tkdocs.com/shipman/events.html